# Animate Iframe on Url Change

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a url rotator that changes the url when someone clicks on the "Next" button, goes to previous url with "Previous" button. I want to add a transition animation between URL Change to it.
The code is :

**Javascript**:

```
var s = [

  "http://google.com",
  "http://yt.be",
];
var adr,
  i,
  x = 0,
  c = s.length;

function next() {
  x += 1;
  if (x > c - 1) {
    x = 0;
  }
  changeSrc();
}

function prev() {
  x -= 1;
  if (x <= 0) {
    x = c - 1;
  }
  changeSrc();
}

function changeSrc() {
  document.getElementById("fm").src = s[x];
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="PREV SITE" name="submit" onclick="prev()" />
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="NEXT SITE" name="submit" onclick="next()" />
</form>
<iframe id="fm" name="fm" style="position:fixed;margin-top:-25px;width:100%;height:95%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Any suggestions for animation ?
If the snippet is not working then view the live demo here: [YoYoBtcRotator.cf](http://yoyobtcrotator.cf)

Comment: You could create another hidden iframe to the left or right of the current one, and then slide in from the left or right depending on previous or next buttons.

Comment: But it would then be a tedious task to create 20 such iframes ! BTW, any way to automate it ?

Comment: You don't need 20! I'll try and make a js fiddle.

Comment: Thanx for help please make it for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JQuery UI `hide()` and `show()` functions to produce the effect you are after.

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es9ejc90/) that I chucked together. I used divs instead of iframes, but you get the same effect.

### Edit

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/es9ejc90/9/) is the updated version that appends a link to the selected div, and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ggutn0rg/) is a version that updates the url of an iframe. The last ones url's dont work due to the site blocking me from iframing them, but any personal site you put in should work perfectly.

Comment: is there any way to make it look 3-D ? Thanks !

Comment: Not using jquery ui, and not using the demo I've given you. I've never made any 3D transitions, does it have to be 3D?

Comment: No, its fine. Like this i wanted to add the links of iframes, which are more than 10, how can i do it ? Earlier i had the links list in js that updated the iframe link after clicking next or previous buttons. please help

Comment: I've added two new jsfiddles, the last one should work perfectly. I would be greatfull if you marked my answer as accepted (the tick) if this solved your problem.

Comment: Just last thing, the url's are showing in text while i want them to be shown as iframes i.e the user should be able to use the site from within it.

Comment: Yep, see the second jsfiddle I put in there. That shows the site. Nothing shows up, because the sites are blocking me from iframing them. Your own sites will show up however.

Comment: thanx for help ! and fast replies :)

Comment: No problem! It'd be great if you marked my answer as correct by clicking the tick :D